# Making internal redirect on submitted links with HTMLPurifier (Munge.php)

Tags: php, redirect, htmlpurifier

I'm trying to setup internal redirect with the help of **HTMLPurifier** library. Most of [documentation](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html) is pretty straight forward and the class for this purpose [URI.Munge](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#URI.Munge) already exists, but there is no examples (all over internet) on how to make this work. Although, I'm not a highly skilled programmer, but documentation doesn't make sense to me on how to set it up, and even additional examples [Here](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-uri-filter.html). Especially where to set **%s**, **%r**, **%t** etc.. and [URI.MungeSecretKey](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#URI.MungeSecretKey).

Submission of text containing external links is done by TinyMCE.
In PHP code I have allowed a href in configuration and added **URI.Munge** class:

```
$uri = $config->getURIDefinition(true);
$uri->addFilter(new HTMLPurifier_URIFilter_Munge(), $config);
```

I guess here should be some additional code...

Submitted code:

```
<a href="http://example.com">Link</a>
```

I'm getting output:

```
<a href="">Link</a>
```

Expect output:

```
<a href="/redirect?s=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com&amp;t=c15354f3953dfec262c55b1403067e0d045a3059&amp;r=&amp;n=a&amp;m=href&amp;p=">Link</a>
```

Can someone give me a clue on how to achieve this? Or at least some sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration mentioned on the page http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html is generally used like this:

```
require_once '/path/to/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('URI.Munge', ...);
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
```

The URI Filters page is for when you want to write your own, custom filters - not for when you want to use the in-built ones! :)

What you probably want is this:

```
require_once '/path/to/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('URI.Munge', '/redirect?s=%s');
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
```

`URI.MungeSecretKey` helps by partially preventing the abuse of your redirection end-point as an arbitrary redirector (which is bad because e.g. then malevolent people will embed links like `https://good.example.com/redirect?s=https://evil.example.com` into emails, so it superficially appears like they're linking to `https://good.example.com` and their link gets a trust boost - yes, this happens, and yes, it works to some degree (and unfortunately, *"some degree"* is all it takes for schemes like this to be profitable to someone)).

If you supply e.g.:

```
require_once '/path/to/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('URI.Munge', '/redirect?s=%s&t=%t');
$config->set('URI.MungeSecretKey', 'foobar');
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
```

Then a URL `https://friendly.example.com` will be turned into (I'm leaving out `urlencode()` on the URL for legibility):

```
/redirect?s=https://friendly.example.com&t=41934069b21c4a3892b61194b90fc537970106ebc9fe79961930a0888b22245f
```

`41934069b21c4a3892b61194b90fc537970106ebc9fe79961930a0888b22245f` is the result of `hash_hmac("sha256", "https://friendly.example.com", "foobar")`. Your redirect end-point can check this value by computing `hash_hmac("sha256", $_GET['s'], "foobar")` and checking it against `$_GET['t']`. If those two match, the redirect was generated by HTML Purifier.

By itself, this isn't a perfect protection against redirector abuse, but it helps.

The shortfalls are described in the documentation of `URI.MungeSecretKey`:

> Please note that it would still be possible for an attacker to procure secure hashes en-mass by abusing your website's Preview feature or the like, but this service affords an additional level of protection that should be combined with website blacklisting.

Does that help?

Comment: WOW! Works like a charm! Thank you for excellent explanation and example code -
now it makes sense to me :)  In a matter of fact I've tried setup you have provided in your code, but I didn't realize that declaration - $uri->addFilter(new HTMLPurifier_URIFilter_Munge(), $config); was killing it all :) Thank you!